# SerializationException occurs only on one Environment

Tags: c#, serialization

I am encountering a “SerializationException“ specifically that an object “is not marked as serializable.” The application is made in C# .NET 3.5. However I only encounter this on one environment and not another, while I would expect to see it on both. What would be the reason that I don’t encounter this on both?

Comment: if it is a class that youcreated, you need to add the `[Serializable]` attribute to the top of it.  But we need to see the code in question to be sure

Comment: Maybe you have an older software version at that Environment where you haven't decorated that class with **SerializableAttribute**

Comment: This is a broad question. What do you exactly mean by "environment"? Are you talking about two different machines? Do both of these "environments" have the same .NET version?

Comment: Does your object use a `Func` or `Action` that you're assigning an annoymous delegate to. If is does then this might be the problem as the delegates are not flagged as serializable.

Comment: The .NET versions are not identical between the two machines. Let me try making them identical. But this would make sense. Thanks!